# Manipulating Order of JOINS in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, join, model

I have the following problem with CakePHP:

In my model, Deposit belongsTo Account, and Account belongsTo Customer.

When querying Deposits, I get the Account information, but not the Customer's, by default.

If I set Deposit->recursive to 2, I get the Customer information (and a whole lot more), but CakePHP esentially throws one SELECT per each deposit, which is quite bad in this case.

So, I did this:

```
'joins' => array(
    array('table'=>'customers', 'alias'=>'Customer', 'type'=>'left', 'foreignKey' => false, 'conditions'=>array('Account.customer_id = Customer.id'))
)
```

which *almost* works...

What I get from that is esentially:

```
SELECT (...) FROM Deposits LEFT JOIN Customers LEFT JOIN Accounts
```

instead of

```
SELECT (...) FROM Deposits LEFT JOIN Accounts LEFT JOIN Customers
```

which of course doesn't work.

Is there anyway to specify that "my custom joins" should go after the "regular model joins"?
Or do I have to manually unbind Deposit from Account, and specify both joins manually?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Containable behavior to select just what you want, so from your Deposits controller:

```
$this->Deposit->find('all', array(
    // conditions
    'contain' => array('Account' => array('Customer'))
));
```

Just be sure to add the `actsAs` variable to the class.  Here's more info.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to unbind models that you want to be at the top and include the appropriate arrays in 'joins' array. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470182/how-to-change-the-sequence-of-joins-in-cakephp) question for details

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but it is still relevant...

Cake does look through existing joins before adding in new joins to satisfy associations. After some digging in dbo_source.php (cake 1.3, also applies to 2.x) I have that by specifying your "joins" exactly how cake builds them you can effectively override the order of the joins.

So, in your case here:

```
'joins' => array(
array(
    'table' => '`accounts`', 
    'alias' => 'Account', 
    'type' => 'Left', 
    'conditions' => '`Deposit`.`account_id` = `Account`.`id`'
),
array(
    'table' => '`customers`', 
    'alias' => 'Customer', 
    'type' => 'Left', 
    'conditions' => '`Account`.`customer_id` = `Customer`.`id`'
)
)
```

Cake using in_array() to do this so note the `` around table and field names, capitalisation of LEFT and not using an array for the conditions as these are required to make the comparison work.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this situation and I was almost stuck then. After doing some search I found that there are 2 ways to do it.

1. Edit the core DboSource.php file to change the joins order. ([How to change the sequence of 'joins' in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470182/how-to-change-the-sequence-of-joins-in-cakephp))
2. Or we need to explicitly specify our association in $joins array. Then use recursive -1 in query.

I hope there are the possible options now. If you have any other interesting way please post here!