# cakephp query with many tables

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a site developed in cakephp 2.0, I have some tables relationed here is an example:
This is my relations:

> ingredients (id,name) has many versions
>
> ingredient_properties(id,property_id,version_id) belongs
>   to properties, versions
>
> properties (id,name,value,group_id,unit_id) has many
>   ingredient_properties and belongs to groups,units
>
> groups (id,name) has many properties
>
> units (id,name) has many properties
>
> versions (id,name,ingredient_id,active) has many ingredient_properties and belongs to ingredients.

I am in the ingredientController.php and I wanto to retrieve all this data where `Version.active=1` and `Version.ingredient_id=2`.

This is my query:

```
$this->set(
        'ingredient',
        $this->Ingredient->Version->find('all', array(
            'recursive' => 2,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Version.active' => 1,
                'Version.ingredient_id' => 2
             )
        ))
);
```

I have many and many queries like this and I want to know if recursive 2 is the best way to retrieve all data of the table that I have explained or there is a better way most quickly (in terms of speed of query not to implement).
I hope that someone can help me to optimize my code because this query works but I don't know if it is the better way to retrieve data of many tables relationed.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked in to the built-in containable behaviour?

Comment: [Read this page of the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

Comment: Thanks I'll read the page immediately I wanto to optimize my query absolutely

Comment: Can someone make me an example with my tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the best way to use `'recursive' => 2` if you want to retrieve so much data. I believe it generates too many queries. Containable behaviour has the same drawback. The best way for me was to [unbind models associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly) and [construct table joins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) on the fly. You can look at an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470182/how-to-change-the-sequence-of-joins-in-cakephp). But you need to know some SQL to understand what you do.

Comment: I understand well sql, but is better to construct table joins or use containable behaviour? Consider that if I have to make joins I have to write more code rather  than containable

Comment: If you want less code use Containable. If you want faster queries use joins.

Comment: It should be faster but I have not done any comparison tests. For my purposes Containable generated too many queries when by using joins I could retrieve everything I needed with a single query.