# CakePHP - Model SQL queries connections

Tags: cakephp

I use the cakePHP framework I have a question about how models handle MySQL query connections. Basically I have a model which I need to set recursive level of 2, to get to some information in a deeper model. Although I have removed all binding of level 2 models which I do not need the framework is still executing a large number of queries to build the result set.

What I want to know is if the framework opens and closes a MySQL connection for every query or does it open a single connection and executes all the queries and then close the connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that CakePHP connect to the database and then executes all queries. Look here for the code: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

You can always unbind model associations and bind them on the fly or build your entire mega query on the fly by using `'joins'` syntax. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470182/how-to-change-the-sequence-of-joins-in-cakephp) question to see an example and at [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) page from the cookbook. I was able to reduce the number of queries from tens to one by correctly joining tables.